# Why am I concluding that the emitter-degenerated CE stage is unilateral?

Tags: analog, feedback, common-emitter

Consider the attached small-signal diagram for an emitter-degenerated CE stage:
[image]
It's been a long day so I must be making an error, but I continue to conclude that this two-port is unilateral (defined as \$y_{12} = 0\$) which seems absurd.

To see this analysis, let's set \$v_i = 0\$ from which it follows that \$i_b = -v_e/r_\pi\$. Now from KCL at the emitter and KCL at the collector and eliminating \$i_o\$ as marked on the graph I arrive at
$$v_e = i_b \left(\frac{1 + (\beta_0 +1)r_0/R_C}{1/R_C +1/R_E +r_0/(R_ER_C)} \right).$$
Inserting my earlier expression for \$i_b\$ to this monstrosity above I conclude that \$v_e = 0\$ (because the LHS is positive and the RHS is negative) and thus that \$i_b = 0\$. Ergo, \$y_{12} = 0\$.

But I have surely gone wrong here because

(1) I "know" this circuit is bilateral since it's a standard example of negative feedback and

(2) My analysis above contradicts that current \$v_o/r_o \neq 0\$ flows in the \$R_E || r_\pi\$ path so that \$v_e \neq 0\$.

Can anyone set me straight as to where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: First of all, it seems to me like a normal double load rather than a common emitter-degenerate.

Comment: @Franc I'm not sure I follow unfortunately?

Comment: I don't see Vo in your math. Y12 is the current at port 1 divided by voltage at port 2 when port 1 is shorted. port 1 is the base so the current is ib and the port 2 is the collector so the voltage is Vo. So Y12 would be ib/Vo

Comment: EE18 - as far as I can follow your analysis, you assume that there will be a current source "gm*v1" even in case vi=0.  I think, such a view shows the limitations  of small signal diagrams. From the physical point of view, this current is the result from vi resp v1 - not vive versa.

Comment: @Pangus I have eliminated \$i_o\$ (which is \$-v_o/R_c\$) in getting to my expression above. I'm not entirely sure why that isn't allowed as I continue to think about it...if you can comment on that in your answer I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure what's wrong with what I've done. In particular (and as you can see in the figure in the OP), all I've done is use that the controlled current source produces $\beta_0i_b = g_mr_\piv_1\$. I'm not sure why this assumption would be false? @LvW

Comment: EE18 - do you agree that both parameters - base current ib and transconductance gm - have a value of zero when the base-emitter voltage is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where your attempt went wrong, but here's mine.

The resistors rpi and RE are parallel and form a current divider. Let's set:

```
RZ = rpi || RE
iZ = -ib + ie
```

With that, we get:

```
ve = -v1 = RZ * iZ                Sign flipped due to ve opposing v1
gm * v1 = -gm * ve
iZ = (vo - ve) / ro - gm * ve     Current through ro summed with dependent current gm*v1
```

Now, substituting `ve = RZ * iZ` and rearranging:

```
iZ = (vo - ve     ) / ro - gm * ve
iZ = (vo - RZ * iZ) / ro - gm * RZ * iZ
iZ = vo / ro - RZ * iZ / ro - gm * RZ * iZ
iZ = vo / ro - (RZ / ro + gm * RZ) * iZ
iZ + (RZ / ro + gm * RZ) * iZ = vo / ro
iZ * (1 + RZ / ro + gm * RZ)  = vo / ro
iZ = vo / (ro * (1 + RZ / ro + gm * RZ))

iZ = vo / (ro + RZ + gm * RZ * ro)
```

Finally, we can multiply with `RZ` to get ve:

```
ve = vo * (RZ / (ro + RZ + gm * RZ * ro))
```

As you can see, ve is just a scaled-down fraction of vo. In turn, the base current is non-zero for any non-zero output voltage. For zero gm, this turns into a simple voltage divider, and for infinite gm, ve is always zero due to infinite negative feedback.

Comment: Thank you, accepted! If you do get the chance at all to understand where I went wrong I would greatly appreciate it (there must be some assumption or division by 0 I did, but I can't tell what), but no worries if not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your derivation is correct. For that circuit itself with no driving sources, all signals (voltages and currents) are, of course, zero. To calculate \$y_{12} \$ parameter, you should assume there is a source driving at the output port \$V_{out} \$ here.

Comment: Other people seem to be saying that \$y_{12} \neq 0\$ so surely I did something wrong? I have assumed a source driving the output and still come to this conclusion I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to what I said and for clarity, a BJT with double load, i.e. with two outputs referred to ground, is the one in the figure:

[image]

Comment: Fair enough, but I think this is just a matter of what people choose to call the given circuit, right? The two sources I use (for instance), Sedra and Smith and Gray, Hurst, Lewis, Meyer each call it an emitter-degenerated common emitter circuit, but in the end it's all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion \$Y_{12}=0\$ is incorrect. You have to assume there is a driving source at \$v_{o}\$ to calculate \$Y_{12}\$

\$Y_{12}\$ is the current at port 1 divided by voltage at port 2 when port 1 is shorted.

Port 1 is the base so the current is \$i_{b}\$ and port 2 is the collector so the voltage is \$v_{o}\$. Therefore

\$Y_{12}=i_{b}/v_{o}\$

Port 1 is shorted so \$v_{i} = 0\$

Here is the equivalent circuit with \$v_{i}\$ shorted

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFmwhc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The sign between \$v_{1}\$ and \$v_{e}\$ is flipped based on the original diagram

\$v_{1}=-v_{e}\$

Next we try to find \$Y_{12}\$

\$i_{b}=v_{e}/r_{\pi}\$

\$i_{1}=\frac{v_{e}}{R_{e}\|r_{\pi}}\$

\$i_{1}=\frac{v_{o}-v_{e}}{r_{o}}+g_{m}v_{1}\$

\$i_{1}=\frac{v_{o}-v_{e}}{r_{o}}-g_{m}v_{e}\$

\$\frac{v_{e}}{R_{e}\|r_{\pi}}=\frac{v_{o}-v_{e}}{r_{o}}-g_{m}v_{e}\$

Solve for \$v_{e}\$

\$v_{e}=\frac{v_{o}}{1+\frac{r_{o}}{R_{E}\|r_{\pi}}+g_{m}r_{o}}\$

plug in \$v_{e}\$ for \$i_{b}\$ equation

\$i_{b}= \frac{v_{o}}{r_{\pi}(1+\frac{r_{o}}{R_{E}\|r_{\pi}}+g_{m}r_{o})}\$

\$Y_{12}=\frac{i_{b}}{v_{o}}=\frac{1}{r_{\pi}(1+\frac{r_{o}}{R_{E}\|r_{\pi}}+g_{m}r_{o})}\$

so \$Y_{12}\$ does not equal zero

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just looking it over, and isn't it the case that \$i_b = -v_e/r_\pi\$?

Answer (score 0):

In what follows, the calculations to obtain the elements of the quadrupole admittance matrix or relative y parameters are reported:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Based on these results, the quadripole is reciprocal only if ro is considered tending to zero.

Comment: Thank you for this! For the \$y_{12}\$ matrix you write that \$i_t = V_a/r_\pi\$. Why is this? I thought \$ V_a\$ was across \$r_o\$ in series with \$r_{\pi} || R_E\$, i.e. \$i_t = V_a/(r_o + r_\pi || R_E)\$?

Comment: @EE18 Thank you. I made some corrections. I hope there are no other errors.